# It is possible that CAN bus node have multiple identifiers?

Tags: can-bus

I want to use CANopen, and by the preconfigured set a device can have more than one COB-ID(as it has different function codes)
I want to know if the CAN bus frame identifier uses CANopen's COB-ID as it is.

Comment: Do you mean if a node in a CANOpen network can have more than one single nodeID to increase the number of possibles PDOs to be sent?

Answer (score 1):

A CANopen node cannot use multiple identifiers at the same time, but it's technically possible to reconfigure the node-ID. According to *CiA301 - CANopen application layer and communication profiles*, during NMT state initialization the parameters of the manufacture specific profile area and of the standardized device profile area are set to their power-on values.

One way to implement this is to assign a default node-ID for the CANopen node. Then reserve a SDO object in the object dictionary to modify the node-ID after reset or power-on. Note that if you want to fully follow CANopen standard, when you change the node-ID, the CAN-ID allocation modify the IDs for the other NMT states and communication objects such as SDO, PDO, etc.

Check [this link](http://www.canopensolutions.com/english/about_canopen/canopen-management.shtml) for further information.